# Select all but this element

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion

I have a few accordions setup and I'd like only one to be open throughout the whole page. I thought that the .not() method would achieve what I wanted however it is just immediately closing the current div.

Here is what I have if anyone can spot where I've gone wrong:

JS

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
$('.accordion-toggle').click(function(){

  //Expand or collapse this panel
  $(this).next().stop().slideToggle('1000');
  $(this).toggleClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

  //Hide the other panels
  $('.accordion-content').not(this).slideUp('1000');

});
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="location1">

<h3 class="accordion-toggle">Opening times <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></h3>
<div class="accordion-content">
<p>List of products available here!</p>
</div>

<h3 class="accordion-toggle">Opening times <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></h3>
<div class="accordion-content">
<p>List of products available here!</p>
</div>

<h3 class="accordion-toggle">Opening times <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></h3>
<div class="accordion-content">
<p>List of products available here!</p>
</div>

<h3 class="accordion-toggle">Opening times <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></h3>
<div class="accordion-content">
<p>List of products available here!</p>
</div>

</div>



<div id="location2">

<h3 class="accordion-toggle">Opening times <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></h3>
<div class="accordion-content">
<p>List of products available here!</p>
</div>

<h3 class="accordion-toggle">Opening times <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></h3>
<div class="accordion-content">
<p>List of products available here!</p>
</div>

<h3 class="accordion-toggle">Opening times <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></h3>
<div class="accordion-content">
<p>List of products available here!</p>
</div>

<h3 class="accordion-toggle">Opening times <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></h3>
<div class="accordion-content">
<p>List of products available here!</p>
</div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
.accordion-content {
  display: none;
  padding:20px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d4d5d7;
}

.accordion-content.default {display: block;}

.accordion-toggle {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size:18px;
  padding:10px 0;
  margin:0;
  border-bottom:1px solid #d4d5d7;
  position:relative;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were pretty close. You should change this line

```
$('.accordion-content').not(this).slideUp('1000');
```

To This:

```
$('.accordion-toggle').not(this).next().slideUp('1000');
```

Since your click function is applied to the `accordion-toggle` class, you have to target that class since `this` is an `accordion-toggle` class element, and you want to filter out all elements that are *not* this object. This will also force you to have to use the `.next()` method since you're looking to slide the next element in the DOM.

**Edit 1:**

In order to remove the `active` class across all of the `#locationX` divs, you should separate this line

```
$(this).toggleClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
```

Into this:

```
$('.active').not(this).removeClass('active');
$(this).toggleClass('active');
```

The way it was written previously, after the `active` class is toggled on the current element, it will only remove that class from all sibling elements, which won't properly affect elements in the other divs. It makes the script a bit longer, but it will remove all of the `active` classes before toggling the class on the current element.

**Edit 2:**

The simplest solution for the whole function is probably the following:

```
$('.accordion-toggle').click(function(){

    //Expand or collapse this panel
    $(this).next().stop().slideToggle('1000');  

    //Hide the other panels
    $('.accordion-toggle').not(this).removeClass('active').next().slideUp('1000');
    $(this).toggleClass('active'); 

});
```

Comment: This works to a certain extent but it doesn't remove the 'active' class from the divs that it closes outside of their container (#location1 / #location2). Is that something else that can be targeted please?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that the `siblings` function can't target elements that aren't in the same container. I've edited my answer.

Comment: That's great thank you, we're certainly getting closer. The code you've supplied works but if I try and close the same accordion that I've just clicked the active class isn't removed. Sorry to be a pain! :/

Comment: That's my fault. The class was being removed from that element, but then immediately being toggled back on because it was the element `this` referred to. It should work now!

Comment: Spot on. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

In your case `this` is the `toggle` not the content (it would also have to be `$(this)` not just `this`, so:

```
$('.accordion-content').not(this).slideUp('1000');
```

Will match all accordion content.

You could try:

```
var $content = $(this).next('.accordion-content');   
$('.accordion-content').not($content).slideUp('1000');
```

As a note, I would set `var $this = $(this);` at the beginning of your handler so that you are not repeatedly creating jQuery objects which is relatively expensive.